# Pass parameters to sqlite query in safer manner

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Here is my method to fetch data older than n number of days/months from sqlite database. Below method will be called with 2 params.

Example,

Fetch data older than 10 days -> GetOldData(10, "days");

Fetch data older than 2 months -> GetOldData(2, "months");

```
private DataTable GetOldData(int valueInNumber, string valueInPeriod)
{ 
   sqliteCommand.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM tblInfo WHERE SavedDate < DATE('Now', 'LocalTime', '-{valueInNumber} {valueInPeriod}')";
   

}
```

Above method works fine. but writing the query in above format is not safe. So, I want to pass these 2 params as sql parameters to the query.

```
sqliteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("period", 2);
sqliteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("term", "days");
```

Tried this with above Parameters.AddWithValue but the condition is not applying.

What should be the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parameters with placeholders like `@paramName` on your query. And in this case, you can concatenate the string value that comes from your function.

```cs
sqliteCommand.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM tblInfo WHERE SavedDate < DATE('Now', 'LocalTime', @param1)";
string value = valueInNumber + " " + valueInPeriod;
sqliteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", value);
```